# normal form for some finite groups, extending the small groups library

Tags: gr.group-theory, sage, gap

I am in need of a normal (that is, canonical) form for (some) finite groups, computable with - for example - gap or sage or any other freely available package.  The goal is to make finite groups available in [FindStat](http://findstat.org).

More precisely: I need an algorithm that takes as input a permutation group and either produces the special symbol "fail", or, if it doesn't, produces a string which distinguishes the group.

For small groups I am currently using the [small groups library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html).  However, would also like to recognise larger symmetric and alternating groups, and direct products of these.

It does not need to be particularly fast.

I am thinking of something along the lines of gap's [StructureDescription](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E), except that it should fail whenever it does not produce a canonical form.

I have no experience with groups, so I am grateful for all hints, the more explicit, the better.

There is a corresponding question for a [canonical form of permutation groups up to conjugacy](https://mathoverflow.net/q/90107/3032).

Comment: For orders less than 500, I like https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html . But that is not what you are asking for.

Comment: I think all of the necessary functionality  for doing what you want is present in GAP, so it would be a question of somebody putting everything to write a package or function to do what you want. Oddly enough, the most difficult problem might be to write down very precise specifications of exactly what you would like this function to do.

Comment: @DerekHolt: it would suffice for me if StructureDescription would stop at the point where the result becomes ambiguous, but I do not know where this is precisely. Would the following be a canonical form when it succeeds?  2. If G is abelian, then decompose it into cyclic factors in "elementary divisors style". 3. Recognize alternating groups, symmetric groups, dihedral groups, quasidihedral groups, quaternion groups, PSL's, SL's, GL's and simple groups not listed so far as basic building blocks. 4. Decompose G into a direct product of irreducible factors.

Comment: I imagine it would not be difficult to give $\mathtt{StructureDescription}$ the option of aborting when the returned valu did not determing $G$ up to isomorphism. Incidentally, it is not always easy to decide if a group decomposes as a direct product. It's OK if there not too many normal subgroups.

Comment: In fact, the ideal thing might be a function that returns "fail" or decomposes the group as a direct product of small groups.  What precisely do you mean with deciding whether it's a direct product not being easy?  Takes a long time or there is no implementation or there is no algorithm?

Comment: Assuming your groups are finite, add possible decompositions can be checked given enough time, but that can be a VERY long time.

Comment: Computing "canonical forms" of groups is a hard problem, I feel you are vastly underestimating the difficult of what you are doing. Note that `` already is ambiguous for groups of order 16...

Comment: Of course there are special cases, like the families of simple groups, and abelian groups, for which "unique names" exist for arbitrary sizes, but beyond that, "naming" groups is fiendishly difficult, and at the same time in many cases not all that useful (though of course sometimes it can be, but then again, you should be careful in specifying what you want to achieve)

Comment: I made good progress by using the source code of StructureDescription.  I first use "DirectFactorsOfGroup" (which takes time, but I do not care for the moment), and then check a few special cases, and finally whether it is a small group.  This is almost good enough for me.

Comment: What (probably) remains: I would like to check whether the given group is a group of coloured permutations - G(r,1,n) - or a group of even signed permutations - G(2,2,n), because these occur often, but I do not know how to do this...

Comment: So do you want a database of groups? Or of isomorphism classes of groups? Or of permutation groups? Or of equivalence classes of permutations groups? I don't think that the property "is a group of signed permutations" is an intrinsic notions of groups.

Comment: @MaxHorn: I want isomorphism classes of finite groups.  So, yes, I thought that the question "is this group isomorphic to G(r,1,n) for some r and some n?" makes sense. If it doesn't, please educate me.  The point is that I want to "name" groups that occur frequently in combinatorics, eg., as automorphism group of some (small) structure.