# Efficient characterisation of the generalized symmetric groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

This is a follow-up to [normal form for some finite groups, extending the small groups library](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288477/3032).

Not being familiar with groups, I wonder whether it is possible to check efficiently whether a group (given as a permutation group) is isomorphic to a [generalized symmetric group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Generalized_symmetric_group).

Initial computer experiments indicate that the parameter $m$ in $\mathbb Z_m\wr\mathfrak S_n$ might be twice the index of the derived subgroup in the group.

From a practical point of view, I am trying to do this with GAP.

Comment: How is the "given group" given? As just some arbitrary permutation group? As a matrix group? By generators and relations? Those are three very different situations from an algorithmic standpoint. The third is in fact an uncomputable problem.

Comment: You could use $\mathtt{RadicalGroup}$ to find the largest solvable normal subgroup (or $\mathtt{FittingSubgroup}$ to find the largest nilpotent normal subgroup) and then try to identify this as $C_m^n$, and the quotient as $S_n$. You might find it more productive to use the GAP Forum mailing list to ask how to do specific things in GAP.

Comment: @DerekHolt: OK, I'll ask the specifics concerning GAP there.  Concerning the mathematics, I encountered a problem with your idea of identifying the Fitting subgroup as $C_m^n$: for $C_2\wr S_4$ it seems that the Fitting subgroup is not Abelian.  Is this an exceptional case?  Also, the group $A_4:C_4$ fits the test but is different from $C_2\wr S_4$.

Comment: Yes I was probably assuming that $n \ge 5$. I would expect that for $n \le 4$ you could do it by testing directly for isomorphism, at least for reasonably small $m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: if you feel like it, perhaps you could convert your comments into an answer (maybe with some explanation).  According to my computer, the exceptional cases seem to be as follows: if $(m,n)=(3,3)$ and if $(m,n)=(2^k,4)$, the Fitting subgroup is not Abelian.  On the other hand, for $n=3$ there are some other groups of order $m^n n!$ where the Fitting group is isomorphic to $C_m^n$ and the quotient is isomorphic to $S_3$.  This happens at least for $m=2$, $m=4$ and $m=5$.

Comment: What I currently do is: 1. compute Fitting subgroup, check that it is Abelian; 2. compute quotient, check that order is $m^n\cdot n!$; 3. compute Abelian invariants, check that Fitting subgroup is $C_m^n$; 4. check that quotient is $S_n$.

Comment: Final comment: replacing the Fitting subgroup with the radical group, it seems that all the false positives go away at the cost that $C_m\wr S_3$ and $C_m\wr S_4$ are not recognised anymore.

Comment: I am unwilling to make this into an answer, because I don't really believe that this question is suitable for a forum devoted to research level mathematics. I appreciate that you are not a specialist in group theory, but what you seem to be  asking for is advice on how to perform certain calculations in GAP, and there are better places available for that. Also, it would be helpful to have some idea of the range of $m$ and $n$ that you have in mind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for the reasons explained in the comment by Derek Holt.

Comment: It's OK for me if the question is closed, although I must say that I was actually not asking for advice on how to use GAP.  I would have been happy with a mathematical answer.  In particular, I still do not know how to recognise $C_m \wr S_3$ and $C_m \wr S_4$ other than testing for isomorphism.